# jQuery: Determining scroll position distance from top of a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div named "article-text" with 200px height, I want to determine the user's scrolling distance from top of "article-text" div.

For instance, if the user scrolls from the top of "article-text" 100px, it would give an alert "you have reached 50% from the top of article".

Sorry, I am a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

By named I'm assuming you mean it has an ID of `article-text`. If not then change `$('#article-text')` to `$('div[name="article-text"]')`. Also by distance I'm assuming that you mean the distance from the **Bottom** of the window's view to the **50%** point of the div. Let me know if you want it differently.

If you want to be able to do other percentages of that div then just change **2** in `($article.height()/2)` to calculate the percentage. So `($article.height()/1)` = 100%, `($article.height()/4)` = 25%, and so on. Removing `+ ($article.height()/2)` will give you the distance from the top of that div.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9Ru2/1/)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var $article = $('#article-text'),
        article50Percent = $article.offset().top + ($article.height()/2),
        distance = article50Percent - ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height());
    console.log(distance);
});
```